# Работа функции strtotime

Tags: php, дата

Поясните как правильно работает функция.Разве она не должна возвращать временную метку?

```
$date = date('m-d-Y', time());
echo strtotime($date);
```

Comment: что вы хотите на выходе получить?

Comment: Временную метку

Comment: это понятно, но в каком формате? в секундах?

Comment: Да именно.Разве функция не должна возвращать это?

Comment: должна. тогда почему бы вам не напечатать `time()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас на выходе из функции `date` получается не корректный формат даты для `strtotime`. Посмотрите возможные формы в документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.date.php

Например: `'m/d/y'` является корректным.

```
$date = date('m/d/y', time());
echo strtotime($date); // 1458284400
```

Comment: я думал strtotime принимает любые форматы

Comment: Спасибо поменял формат и действительно выводится.